# Finding minimum distance traveled with specified deceleration from starting speed

Tags: classical-mechanics

Let's say there is an object flying around (in a straight line), which has a constant speed $v$ and zero acceleration.

In some moment I can apply a constant deceleration $a$ to that object and I need to find a distance $d$ which will be traveled until the object stops.

Based on this formulas: $v = at$, $d = \frac{1}{2} at^2$ I wrote this:

$$d = \frac{v^2}{2a} $$

My question, is that correct and if not, what is ?

Comment: Yes, correct.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. Another way to solve this would have been to rearrange the following equation:
$$v_f^2 = v_o^2 + 2ax$$
Because $v_f=0$ we can rewrite:
$$x = {-v_o^2 \over 2a}$$
We can ignore the negative sign because the acceleration is negative, and will therefore cancel it out.